# How to give write storage permissions in android 13

Tags: android

unable to create directory in android 13

i have used READ_MEDIA_IMAGES permission for reading the images from gallery but images are not saving in storage

Comment: We dont see you saving images to storage. Post your code please. And if you have questions then ask them.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.